# How to use the id from the response into the next request endpoint?

Tags: soapui, web-api-testing

I am using SOAPUI and i am currently saving the response which is id into the global property called id.

this is what i am saving in the global property:

`{"id": "vnjGZxXVqlwGga6UVXIAhQQ7JpI="}`

```
//imports
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

//grab the response
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
//define a JsonSlurper
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)

def id = jsonSlurper.id
// sets the global property called PackageId
com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.setPropertyValue("PackageId", id)
```

Now i want to use that id in the next request for example - test.com/api/{id}

How would i do that in SOAPUI?. I tried few things about but i do not seem to get it

This is what I am trying but not having any luck:

test.com/api/{$id}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the way you proceed, storing into a global variable, you'll need to use a statement like this :

```
def recovered_id= context.expand('${#Global#PackageId}' )
```

Depending on its range you could store it at a lower level (testCase or testSuite level)

If it is located in a single testCase, you may return the value at the end of your groovy script then call it directly referring the testStep's result to avoid using custom properties.

Alexandre